# UITableViewCell separatorInsets in iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

How do you set the separatorInsets of a table view cell back to their default values programmatically?  I want to change them for some cells but not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following way :

```
 if (indexPath.row == {your row number}){
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0);
    }
```

In iOS7 table view has default 15 left inset for separator,you can change it as per your requirement by using above code.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve setting the values explicitly.  Apple could decide to change the default values in a later version of iOS.

Comment: This is bad, because separatorInsets are actually different on iPhone 7 Plus.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
```

According to documentation,

> `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`
>   The separator cell has a single line running across its width. This is the default value. Available in iOS 2.0 and later.